# Split a string into an array, and assign a value based on their letter?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not asking you to code it for me or anything, snippets of code or just pointing me in the right direction will help me out a lot.

This is what I'm basically trying to do, you have the word "abcdefg"

I want it to split up the string into an array (or whatever works best?) , then assign a value based on what letter is stored into the array. (based on the alphabet , a = 1 , b = 2 , c = 3 , z = 26)

so abcdefg will turn into something like

```
$foo("a" => 1, "b" =>2, "c" => 3, etc..);
```

but obviously if "abcdefg" was "zaj", the array would be "z" => 26 , "a" => 1 , "j" => 10

Basically, convert a string of letters into their alphabetical num value sorta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps that has been put to implement this.

- Generate an alphabet array (alphabets starting from index 1)
- Get the value which which you want to generate as an array.
- Split them up with `str_split`
- Using a `foreach` construct search them in the earlier alphabet array that was created using `array_search`
- When found just , just grab their key and value and put it in the new array.

---

```
<?php
$alph[]='Start';
foreach(range('a','z') as $val)
{
    $alph[]=$val;
}

$makethisvalasarray='zaj';
$makethisvalasarray=str_split($makethisvalasarray);

foreach($makethisvalasarray as $val)
{
    $newarr[$val]=array_search($val,$alph);
}

print_r($newarr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [z] => 26
    [a] => 1
    [j] => 10
)
```

Comment: I already know about str_split, but I'm having an issue assigning the values based upon if what letter it is. I will look again at the php documentation, maybe i missed something.

Answer (score 1):

The functions you need are:

- [str_split](http://php.net/str_split)
- [ord](http://php.net/ord)
- [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

With those functions you can solve this problem in a very small number of lines of code.

Comment: @user3106858 using `ord` you might need to use `strtolower` as well as subtract 96 from the result.

Comment: I was noticing that also. Thanks again. It's sorta confusing me but ill see what I can do with this. :)

Comment: @user3106858 the result of `ord` is in ascii so you need to subtract 96 to make it ordered as in a=1, b=2, etc.

Comment: A typical fragment of code when doing these kinds of manipulations is something like: `ord($letter) - ord('a')`.